# Can you specify just the host portion of an A record in a bind zone file?

Tags: bind

Say I have a zone file with entries like this:

`gateway            A       192.168.1.3`

Is there some way I can specify the network part as a prefix, say 192.168.1 and then only list the host part in the A records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with a standard bind.

Related, you have the `$ORIGIN` and `$GENERATE` macros, but they won't help you doing what you need.

You can either preprocess your zone files if using bare text files, or use another backend (see bind DLZ project).

Comment: Interesting.  Since I'm already using ansible on this project, I might just template the zone files as an ansible template then.